# Ruby implicit inheritance of modules / classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I defined one class `SomeClass` that includes methods with basic functionality. This class is defined in the `Foo` module.

```
# foo/
#   |--some_class.rb

module Foo
    class SomeClass
        def some_method
            puts "Hi!"
        end
    end
end
```

I also have two other modules: `Bar` and `Baz`. I want to include the entire namespacing of `Foo` inside of `Bar` and `Baz`, and inherit all methods defined under `Foo`, and thus to be able to overwrite `Foo` methods.

I also want to be able to overwrite this method only by specifying a new file in the right folder:

```
# baz/
#   |--foo/
#     |--some_class.rb

module Baz
    module Foo
        class SomeClass < ::Foo::SomeClass
            def some_method 
                puts "Hey!"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This works fine. However, I want to be able to use `Bar::Foo::SomeClass.some_method` without having to create *bar/foo/some_class.rb*, and define empty modules and an empty SomeClass.

The same applies to inheritance of modules (by including).

Is there a way do accomplish this easily by using include, extend, or require, or something else? Since this is part of a Rails project (under the lib folder), can I use autoloading in a specific way?

The reason that I want to accomplish this is because I have many classes and modules with classes in it under `Foo`. The `Bar` and `Baz` modules should be able to inherit all modules/classes under `Foo`, and overwriting instance or class methods where it is needed by creating an explicit file. I would like to avoid creating a file for each class or module `Foo` has for `Bar` and `Baz`.

I have the following solution so far. I defined two new files: *bar.rb* and *baz.rb*. In *bar.rb*:

```
module Bar
    def self.const_missing(name)
        klass = Object.const_get(name.to_s) if name.to_s =~ /Foo/
        return klass if klass
        raise
    rescue
        super
    end
end

> Bar
=> Bar # as expected
> Foo
=> Foo # as expected
> Bar::Foo
=> Foo # works!
> Bar::Foo::SomeClass
=> Foo::SomeClass # right
> Baz::Foo::SomeClass
=> Foo::SomeClass # not right...
```

I am not sure if I am on my way to a good solution now. Any feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it a Rails or a plain Ruby project?

Comment: Part of a Rails project. It's residing in the lib/ folder.

Comment: So please mention it in your question. There's no autoloading in plain ruby.

Comment: very nice question